# Tkinter Intvar updates only once, does not show in entry

Tags: python, tkinter

I am building a Tkinter app where a user scans a QR code, add some data and generates a label to print.

I'm currently building the function to create the user input form and I run into a problem. I have a function to create 6 buttons, and 3 entries. The buttons should increase or decrease the value in the entry. All 3 entries have a default value of 0.

The problem is, the buttons only set the value to 1 or -1, and the entry itself does not get updated.

What am I missing? This is my first time programming with Tkinter and I really could use some help...

```
class MainDialog:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.frame = Frame(self.master)
        self.button1 = Button(self.frame, text = 'New Window', width = 25, command = self.new_window)
        self.int_e = ['box', 'bag', 'dry']
        self.build_items()
        self.frame.pack()
    def build_items(self):
        for i in range(len(self.int_e)):
            self.b_inc = Button(self.frame, text='+', width=2, bg='white', relief=GROOVE, command=lambda : self.qty(i, '+'))  
            self.b_dec = Button(self.frame, text='-', width=2, bg='white', relief=GROOVE, command=lambda : self.qty(i, '-'))        
            self.e_qty = Entry(self.frame, width=4, textvariable=i)
            self.b_inc.grid(row=i, column=0, pady=10)
            self.e_qty.grid(row=i, column=1, pady=10)
            self.b_dec.grid(row=i, column=2, pady=10)
    def new_window(self):
        self.newWindow = Toplevel(self.master)
        self.app = QRDialog(self.newWindow)
        
    def qty(self, variable:IntVar, method:str) -> None:
        item = variable.get()
        if method == "+":
            item += 1
        elif method == "-":
            item -= 1
        else:
            print("Error: Invalid method given")
        variable.set(item) # Tell tkinter that we want to change its value
```

Comment: Right now you are getting the value out of the `IntVar`, changing it and printing it out. You never tell `tkinter` that you changed that value.

Comment: Two problems. №.1) `item =+ 1` should be `item += 1` in order to add one to `item`. №.2) After updating the value of `item` you need to call the `IntVar`'s `set()` method to update it — however you can't do that because it can no longer be referenced due to the `item = item.get()` you did at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
def qty(self, variable:IntVar, method:str) -> None:
    item = variable.get()
    if method == "+":
        item += 1
    elif method == "-":
        item -= 1
    else:
        print("Error: Invalid method given")
    variable.set(item) # Tell tkinter that we want to change its value
```

I used `<IntVar>.set(<new value>)` to set the new value. Also `self.master.update()` doesn't do what you think it does. Look at `tkinter`'s unofficial documentation [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20201111171246/https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/).

Also you have a syntax error in your code. If you want to add 1 to a variable and store the result in the same variable, you should use `item += 1` not `item =+ 1`. Same goes for the `-=`.

--

**EDIT**

I just noticed that there are a few other problems in your code like:

- setting `textvariable` to a normal python `int`
- not using `var=var` inside the `lambda` like this: `lambda var=var: ...`

But this is your code fixed:

```py
import tkinter as tk


class MainDialog:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.button1 = tk.Button(self.frame, text = 'New Window', width = 25, command = self.new_window)
        self.int_e = ['box', 'bag', 'dry']
        self.build_items()
        self.frame.pack()
    def build_items(self):
        for i in range(len(self.int_e)):
            var = tk.IntVar()
            self.b_inc = tk.Button(self.frame, text='+', width=2, bg='white', relief=tk.GROOVE, command=lambda var=var: self.qty(var, '+'))  
            self.b_dec = tk.Button(self.frame, text='-', width=2, bg='white', relief=tk.GROOVE, command=lambda var=var: self.qty(var, '-'))        
            self.e_qty = tk.Entry(self.frame, width=4, textvariable=var)
            self.b_inc.grid(row=i, column=0, pady=10)
            self.e_qty.grid(row=i, column=1, pady=10)
            self.b_dec.grid(row=i, column=2, pady=10)
    def new_window(self):
        self.newWindow = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
        self.app = QRDialog(self.newWindow)
        
    def qty(self, variable:tk.IntVar, method:str) -> None:
        item = variable.get()
        if method == "+":
            item += 1
        elif method == "-":
            item -= 1
        else:
            print("Error: Invalid method given")
        variable.set(item) # Tell tkinter that we want to change its value


root = tk.Tk()
MainDialog(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I edited my code but now it returns AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: @nvsch Can you please edit the code in the question with the new code + traceback? Also try adding `print(variable)` at the start of that function. What does it print out? A `IntVar` object or a normal python `int`

Comment: You might also want to mention that you changed `item =+1` to `item += 1`. That might not be obvious to the OP.

Comment: @BryanOakley Ok, I thought it was just a typo. As OP's code wouldn't even compile/run. Given that OP says that *the buttons only set the value to 1 or -1*, the code is running and is printing the value.

Comment: `item =+ 1` isn't a syntax error, btw, it just means `item = +1`.

Comment: @martineau Oh, ok but I guess OP didn't want that. Something new that I learned today. Now it seems kind of obvious :D

Comment: No they didn't. I think they wanted to do a `+=`  but coded it wrong — which I didn't notice until very late in the game. That's what lead me to previously claim that the former wasn't working.

Comment: Just updated the code, must be doing something terribly wrong :\

Comment: @nvsch Edited my answer. I tested the code and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

This code is working for me, thank you for pointing me in the right direction :)

EDIT:

Used @TheLizzard his version instead. Seemed cleaner than my own code :)